# Prove that a parallelepiped with the property that the distance between each two opposite edges is the same is a cube.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Prove that a parallelepiped with the property that the distance between each two opposite edges is the same is a cube.

(managed to prove that the sides are congruent rhombs and don't know how to continue, any help would be appreciated)

Comment: What you proved also implies that the diagonals of each face are congruent.

Comment: Is there an example of such parallelepiped with congruent rhombic faces (and not a cube), if you suspect that question statement is not always true?

Comment: @peterwhy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonal_trapezohedron

Comment: @diana: Are you sure? Can we convincingly make a cube made up of edges only ( no faces) and pull apart a pair of opposite vertices of the longest diagonal?

Comment: It would be interesting to see your proof that the faces are congruent rhombs, so please include this in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\a{{\bf a}}\def\b{{\bf b}}\def\c{{\bf c}}$
Let the parallelepiped be defined by a triple of non-collinear vectors $a,b,c$.

There are two pairs of opposite $c$-edges, the distances between the edges in these pairs being:
$$
\frac{|(a+b)\times c|}{|c|}\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{|(a-b)\times c|}{|c|},
$$
respectively, so one concludes:
$$
|a\times c+b\times c|=|a\times c-b\times c|.
$$
This means $(a\times c)\perp(b\times c)$. Similarly $(a\times b)\perp(c\times b)$ and $(b\times a)\perp(c\times a)$.

Geometrically this means that the three (non-parallel) faces of the parallelepiped are perpendicular to each other. This in turn means that the three (non-parallel) edges of the parallelepiped are perpendicular to each other, so that it is a rectangular parallelepiped (cuboid).

Finally it follows from $a^2+b^2=b^2+c^2=c^2+a^2$ that $|a|=|b|=|c|$.